# Wordpress Theme + SMOF Slider

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, themes

I'm currently developing a Wordpress theme for a personal website and decided to use the Slightly Modded Options Framework [SMOF] to make things easy. Everything has gone pretty well so far, it's indeed an awesome framework. Today I decided to use the built-on slider option the came within the Framework and implement it on my theme and here is where I found my self a little bit lost.

I managed to make the theme and framework show the slideshow, but it won't rotate/circle/slide/fade the images. It's only showing the first image, it stay still and won't change slides.

---

Here is my code in case that someone has knowledge with SMOF:

This is what I have on my functions.php:

```
    $of_options[] = array(  "name"  => "Homepage Slideshow",
            "desc"  => "Slider Option Description",
            "id"    => "homepage_slider",
            "std"   => "",
            "type"  => "slider"
        );
```

---

This is what I have on my theme index.php:

```
    <?php $slides = $data['homepage_slider']; if ($slides) { ?>
    <!-- Start my Precio... uhum! I mean Slider -->
    <?php
        foreach ($slides as $slide) {

        }           
    ?>

    <?php if (!empty ($slide['link'])) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $slide['link']; ?>" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($slide['title'])); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $slide['url']; ?>" width="950" height="369px" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($slide['title'])); ?>" style="height: 369px; width: 100%;"/>
</a>

    <?php } else { ?>

<img src="<?php echo $slide['url']; ?>" width="950" height="369px" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($slide['title'])); ?>" style="height: 369px; width: 100%;"/>                       
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if (count($slides) > 1) { ?>

    <!-- Die Slider! -->

    <?php
        } // End count
    ?>

    <?php
        } // End if
    ?>
```

Probably the issue resides on the loop, but honestly I have tried many ways and couldn't make it swap images. I'll really appreciate any tips and directions that help me work this out. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I am also using smof v 1.5 in a wordpress theme project. I've faced the same problem but after some research i've solved the issue. By using the following codes you can get the slider's each slide's values.

```
    <?php 
    global $smof_data;
    $slides = $smof_data['example_slider']; //get the slides array

    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
        echo $slide['title'];
        echo $slide['url'];
        echo $slide['link'];
        echo $slide['description'];
    }
    ?>
```

By using this code you can access each option element of smof and the key is "global $smof_data;" its not documented but i got if after reading ninezeroseven wordpress theme admin options files. Authors of ninezeroseven used this SMOF and i got the clue from the author coding. I've tried global variable $smof_data instead of $data and its works.

Comment: Nice @HafeezAnsari . I'll give it a try when I start working in a new theme. I did find another issue with my coding that was preventing the slideshow of cycling/sliding.  

The issue was inside the **foreach**. I found that I was closing the **foreach** before even launching the slides. Si I think thats another issue I had.  

Thanks a lot for your tips, I'll definitely give that code a try and I'll let know how things go.